# Redundant server information in my Flask API response

Tags: python-2.7, rest, flask

I'm writing an API in a python Flask app.

```
@app.route('/result', method=['GET'])
def result():
  data = {}
  data['age'] = 18
  data['name'] = 'Jack'
  return jsonify(result=data)
```

**EDIT:** I use Ajax to call the API,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/result",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      data = eval(data);
      // other actions
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
  }
)
```

Why sometimes when I call this API, there are some redundant server information added to the API response body and I cannot parse it as valid json . Like,

Expected result:

```
{
  "result": {
    "age": 18,
    "name": "Jack"
  }
}
```

Actual result:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 187252
Server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/2.7.14
{"result":{"age":18, "name":"Jack"}}
```

For what reason this will happen, Can anyone provide some possible thought?

Comment: The http response has headers- the content of the response is valid JSON. What are you using to send requests?

Comment: @PaulBecotte I'm using ajax in my js frontend

Comment: Those information are HTTP response headers and your JSON is in the HTTP response body. Can you show the snippet on how you parse the response in your front end?

Comment: @erikng has updated the question

Answer (score 0):

just need return json data and front-end tell ajax contentType is json !

```
return jsonify(data)
```

here is my example:

**back-end**

```
@main.route('/api/data')
def foo():
    return jsonify({"bar": True})
```

**front-end(javascript ajax)**

```
function ajax(method, url, data, callback) {
    var obj = {
        type: method,
        url: window.location.origin + url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (a) {
            callback(a);
        }, error: function (err) {
            if ((err.responseJSON).constructor == Object)
                Object.keys(err.responseJSON).length || (err.responseJSON = {'error': err.statusText});
            else if ((err.responseJSON).constructor == Array)
                err.responseJSON.length || (err.responseJSON = {'error': err.statusText});
            callback(err.responseJSON);
        }
    };
    data && (obj.data = JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax(obj);
}


ajax('GET', '/api/data', null, function (a) {
    a.error ? $.growl.error({message: a.error}) : console.log(a);    
});
```

the browser console will see `{"bar": true}`